# Chrome Sockets API Behaves Differently on Chrome OS (vs. Ubuntu, Windows)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, mdns

I have a sample Chrome packaged app which uses the Chrome sockets API to perform DNS service discovery. The heavy lifting is borrowed from the example here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/mdns-browser

I just use service names such as `_pdl-datastream._tcp.local` (instead of the default of `_services._dns-sd._udp.local`).

On both my Ubuntu and Windows setups (Chrome 25.0.1364.172), the app can successfully find my network printer; I can list its IP address and service instance name. However, it fails in Chrome OS on my Samsung Chromebook (Chrome 25.0.1364.173); nothing is found.

Any idea what the problem might be? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check if it's the default firewall. On a Chromebook by default I believe all incoming connections are blocked. If you're running in dev mode you can do the following to allow all incoming udp traffic to test whether this is the problem:

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+T to bring up a terminal window and type the following
2. shell
3. sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT

Comment: Going through this procedure fixed the problem! However, I'd like to understand whether these firewall rules are subject to change in the future, as users can't be expected to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chromebooks default to a restrictive firewall. However, if the incoming packet matches an outgoing one, the incoming packet should be permitted. Here's the [list of firewall rules](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/init.git;a=blob;f=iptables.conf;h=8325f81274e7672fabb762679850f2301a604144;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the firewall rules! It looks like UDP is being filtered very aggressively. Do you know whether these rules are in a state of flux?

Comment: Answering my own question - it does look like these values are changing. My existing `iptables.conf` does not contain the line `. /usr/sbin/netfilter-common` or any below it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223004) created by Haw-Bin, this is verified as fixed since end of 2013.