# chrome.socket UDP API useless on Chromebook?

Tags: udp, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am working on a Chrome packaged app that requires multicast communication over the local network and is specifically targeting Chromebook users.  The 'Network Communication' documentation on the packaged app site is outdated and the chrome.socket API documentation is lacking.  I was able to get some idea of how to get multicast working by looking through Chrome's 'multicast' sample app (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/multicast).

I tested my app by loading it into the Chrome browser on my Mac and everything worked great.  I loaded it onto my Chromebook and multicast did not work.  I then tried the 'multicast' sample app on my Mac and Chromebook with the same result.  The 'multicast' sample app is a chat app.  When loaded on both computers on the same network, everything works as expected on the Mac - I can send chat messages out and receive chat messages.  On the Chromebook I can send chat messages but not receive them - including the ones that the Chromebook sent.

According to this post - [Chrome Sockets API Behaves Differently on Chrome OS (vs. Ubuntu, Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555657/chrome-sockets-api-behaves-differently-on-chrome-os-vs-ubuntu-windows) - it looks like Chromebook has a restricted firewall that is blocking UDP packets.  I followed the instructions on the post to turn on developer mode and allow UDP packets and that allowed my app to run as expected, but that is not a solution for me.  I can't expect Chromebook users to run in developer mode to run my app.

Anyone know if it is possible to allow UDP packets on the Chromebook without going into developer mode?  Is there an undocumented permission I can add to my manifest to override the Chromebook UDP restrictions (this seems possible since the 'udp-multicast-membership' permission included in the 'multicast' sample app is undocumented)?  This seems like a long shot but chrome.socket.create can be given optional socket options which don't appear to be documented anywhere.  Maybe there is something I can add there?  And why have Chrome sample apps that don't run on a Chromebook???

---UPDATE---

In case someone is having a similar problem, it looks like this has already been filed as a bug and been looked at just within the past couple of weeks.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=275737

I have no idea when it will actually make its way to a Chromebook update.

Comment: The 'Network Communication' documentation I referenced: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html

chrome.socket API docs: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> I have no idea when it will actually make its way to a Chromebook
>   update.

usually ChromeOS follows the same release schedule as desktop chrome, with new stable versions coming out about every 6 weeks. But because of the holidays in December when lots of people are on vacation, there is sometimes a hiccup. You can give the dev channel a try and see if the fix showed up there yet: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1086915?hl=en